# convert 3d numpy tensor into 2d pandas array where each cell stores an array?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I can initialize a 2D pandas array and then sweep over the indices of the numpy tensor to index and store the array at each cell in the dataframe, e.g.,

```
data_3d=np.random.rand(2,3,4)
for i in np.arange(2):
   for j in np.arange(3):
      df.iloc[i,j]=data_3d[i,j]
```

Is there a convenience function to do this type of data structuring in pandas?

Comment: It's not recommend to store numpy array in yoru cell. You should use `MultiIndex` to store 3d data. For example, index can be `(i,j)` and column would be `k`, so you'd get a `6x4` DataFrame

Comment: You could just use `pd.DataFrame.from_records(data_3d)`

Comment: @Nick's suggestion resolved this